# How to use END {} in awk when there is no end to the input?

Tags: awk, tail

Say I'm using a command like `tail -f ./somefile` as input into my `awk` command.  And I want to continually sum a count of matches using awk, almost like running a `| wc -l` at the end of a command, but where it would continue receiving the input...when AWK sums the input it displays it with the `END{}` part of the command but since it's still receiving input, the `END{}` part of the command never runs...so how do I get `awk` to keep receiving input as it comes from the `tail -f ./somefile` command?  Is there a looping mechanism for this I could use in the `awk` code segment instead of using `END{}`?

Comment: Can’t you move your processing from the `END` block to a record pattern block?

Comment: +1 ... at its simplest, just removing the `END` pattern so your `{...}` is evaluated for every line... if you want to get fancy, use modulo arithmetic like `!(NR%n)` to evaluate every *n*th line

Comment: @StephenKitt Forgive me, I’m a bit new to awk, the record processing block it the middle one with no label?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention how exactly "matches" are being made, so I'm going to assume a line that matches `/pattern/ {}` rules would increase a count...

> And I want to continually sum a count of matches using `awk`, almost like running a `| wc -l` at the end of a command

If the input is endless, I guess you would like to display the count every time it was incremented?

Basically, don't use `END {}` rule in this case; just print the counter out where you incremented it; like this example AWK program:

```
# Initializer
BEGIN {
    counter=0;
}

# Pattern A
/^COUNT$/ {
    ++counter;
    print counter;
}

# Pattern B
/^HERE$/ {
    ++counter;
    print counter;
}
```

This program will count (and display the counter value) every time a line `COUNT` or `HERE` appear in the input.

If you have a lot of patterns to match and would like to minimize code repetition, you can use [AWK function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Definition-Syntax.html#Definition-Syntax) to combine count and display into one operation:

```
# Initializer
BEGIN { counter=0; }

# Count and Display Function
function count() {
    ++counter;
    print counter;
}

# Pattern A
/^COUNT$/ { count(); }

# Pattern B
/^HERE$/ { count(); }
```

Screenshot (both programs above give identical output):

[image]